# What is the location for windbg Preview in windows 10?And how to rename a project name in visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, windbg

I got location for windbg in here but opening this exe file it looks different from windbg preview 
:- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe"

I  was unable to change the name so I made another project and copy paste the code now I am getting this error :
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for CDAnalysis.exe

Comment: The title asks two questions at one. Please ask one question at a time only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WinDbg Preview is a UWP app, so its binaries span in multiple locations.

Its launcher is at `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\WinDbgX.exe`.

Comment: In my case on Windows 10 the path was %LocalAppData%\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\WinDbgX.exe